# Override functions multiple times for inheritant call stack logging

Tags: windows, powershell, scope, overriding, powershell-5.0

Let's assume the following CmdLets:

**Write-MyColl**

```
function Write-MyColl {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [psobject] $InputObject
    )

    $verb = Get-Command Write-Verbose
    $fixedName = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
    function Write-Verbose ($Object) {
        & $verb "[$fixedName] $Object"
    }

    if ($InputObject.name) {
        Write-Verbose "Writing `$InputObject's Name: `"$($InputObject.name)`""
    }
}
```

**New-MyColl**

```
function New-MyColl {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]] $Names
    )

    $verb = Get-Command Write-Verbose
    $fixedName = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
    function Write-Verbose ($Object) {
        & $verb "[$fixedName] $Object"
    }

    Write-Verbose "Names: $Names"
    foreach ($name in $Names) {
        @{
            id = 123;
            name = $name
        } | Write-MyColl
    }
}
```

As you can see `New-MyColl` overrides [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Verbose?view=powershell-5.0) with it's own `Write-Verbose`. This works perfectly and outputs:

> ```
> VERBOSE: [New-MyColl] Names: [...]
> ```

Now, when `Write-MyColl` is invoked it *should* override `Function:\Write-Verbose` from `New-MyColl` and I want it to output something like:

> ```
> VERBOSE: [New-MyColl] [Write-MyColl] Writing `$InputObject's Name: "[...]"
> ```

As you might already think, it doesn't work. `Write-Verbose` recursively calls itself until the end of days. I already tried local function definitions and local variables, but they won't be visible to the invoked CmdLet.

I think for my specific use-case, I will use [`Get-PsCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-PSCallStack?view=powershell-5.0), however I'd love to see a solution to override overriden functions like described above.

What's hard for me to understand is, why the 2nd `Write-Verbose` calls itself, so `$verb` seemingly points to a function, which is not yet defined. Shouldn't it point to the prior defined function? I already tried to `Remove-Item` the funtion at the end of the script, but it didn't change anything.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this *call-stack-behavior*?

Comment: That's why I thought, a kind of cascaded override would work. But even with a given scope like `$local:verb` this recursion happens. What if we set the variable's name randomly?

Comment: Wow, (almost) perfect! The only thing here is, that `-Verbose` isn't valid in the inner function. I worked around passing `BoundParameters["Verbose"].IsPresent`. Would accept this (along with some explanation) as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [PetSerAI's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962715/override-functions-multiple-times-for-inheritant-call-stack-logging?noredirect=1#comment78913817_45962715), I came to the following solution:

```
New-Item function::local:Write-Verbose -Value (
    New-Module -ScriptBlock { param($verb, $fixedName, $verbose) } -ArgumentList @(
        (Get-Command Write-Verbose), 
        $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName, 
        $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Verbose"].IsPresent
    )
).NewBoundScriptBlock{
    param($Message)
    if ($verbose) {
        & $verb -Message "=>$fixedName $Message" -Verbose
    } else {
        & $verb -Message "=>$fixedName $Message"
    }
} | Write-Verbose
```

The `-Verbose` Parameter isn't passed to the newly created function; that's why I added it to the `-ArgumentList`. I'm sure, it's not very pretty, but it does exactly what it should. Overwrite `Write-Verbose` for each call.

Now the output looks like:

> ```
> VERBOSE: =>[New-MyColl] Names: [...]
> VERBOSE: =>[New-MyColl]=>[Write-MyColl] Writing `$InputObject's Name: "[...]"
> ```